# Flipper debugger error Failed to start flipper-server

Tags: react-native, flipper

It is my first attempt to use the flipper debugger but it doesn't seem to be starting. It threw error

> Failed to start flipper-server Error: Unable to start server at port
> 9088 due to
> {"code":"EACCES","errno":"EACCES","syscall":"listen","address":"0.0.0.0","port":9088,"name":"Error","message":"listen
> EACCES: permission denied 0.0.0.0:9088","stack":"Error: listen EACCES:
> permission denied 0.0.0.0:9088\n at Server.setupListenHandle [as
> _listen2] (net.js:1296:21)\n at listenInCluster (net.js:1361:12)\n at Server.listen (net.js:1447:7)\n at S
> (file:///D:/Program%20Files/Flipper-win/resources/app.asar/bundle.js:104:857)\n
> at new Promise ()\n at SecureServerWebSocket.start
> (file:///D:/Program%20Files/Flipper-win/resources/app.asar/bundle.js:104:538)\n
> at createServer
> (file:///D:/Program%20Files/Flipper-win/resources/app.asar/bundle.js:30:679)\n
> at ServerController.init
> (file:///D:/Program%20Files/Flipper-win/resources/app.asar/bundle.js:7:1715)\n
> at async FlipperServerImpl.connect
> (file:///D:/Program%20Files/Flipper-win/resources/app.asar/bundle.js:6:7506)\n
> at async start
> (file:///D:/Program%20Files/Flipper-win/resources/app.asar/bundle.js:3:1501)"}

In my App Inspect, it doesn't show any devices too so I'm guessing it's because of the error above or it's something else? Cause I have my physical device connected to it and running `adb devices` shows the device in the listing.

And in the Setup Doctor section, it gave the warning. Not sure if this is something needed too.

[image]

I'm using flipper desktop on windows V0.136.0

Answer (score 0):

i was having the same problem, but with a different port. it turned out that my port was excluded by windows. to check if your port 9088 is excluded, open cmd as administrator, and run this command

```
netsh interface ipv4 show excludedportrange protocol=tcp
```

if your port was in the list, you can know which application is reserving this port by running

```
netstat -ano
```

check for protocol tcp and the port number, when you see the row, check the process id, then open task manager as administrator and go to details tab and compare the process id(PID) you should know which application is reserving this port.

i wasn't able to unreserve my port because it was reserved by system process, and i got access denied message every time.

you can launch flipper with different port, check [flipper custom port](https://fbflipper.com/docs/custom-ports/)

my case was

```
env FLIPPER_PORTS=1111,2222 ./flipper
```

in windows will be

```
set FLIPPER_PORTS=1111,2222& flipper.exe
```